# How to clear Slide Master of all information in PowerPoint using VBA?

Tags: vba, loops, slide, powerpoint

I would like to open every PowerPoint (*.pptx) in current folder and clear the Slide Master of all images and text boxes and then save.

(It says my post is mostly code so I need to add more detail, so here is a quote by George Washington, "Associate with men of good quality if you esteem your own reputation; for it is better to be alone than in bad company")

New code

```
Sub DeleteSlideMasterShapes()
    Dim i As Long
    Dim shp As Shape

    With ActivePresentation
        For i = .Designs.Count To 1 Step -1
            For Each shp In .Designs(i).SlideMaster.Shapes
                shp.Delete
            Next
        Next i
    End With
End Sub

Sub loopFiles()

Dim fso As New FileSystemObject
Dim fil As File
Dim fold As Folder
Dim yourfolder As String

Set fold = fso.GetFolder(Application.ActivePresentation.Path)

For Each fil In fold.Files

    If InStr(1, fil.Name, ".pptx") > 0 Then
        Application.Presentations.Open fil.Path

        Call DeleteSlideMasterShapes

        ActivePresentation.Save
        ActivePresentation.Close

    End If

Next fil

End Sub
```

Comment: You need to have a minimum of 1 Slide Master. You can't delete all slidemaster. If you try to delete the last one, it will throw an error. it is like trying to delete all sheets in a workbook. Regarding clearing the SM, can you explain what exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I have slide masters that include images and text boxes in the heading and I want to clear them of the information currently in them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Further to my comments, if you want to delete the slide master then use this

```
Sub DeleteSlideMaster()
    Dim i As Long

    With ActivePresentation
        On Error Resume Next
        For i = .Designs.Count To 1 Step -1
            .Designs(i).SlideMaster.Delete
        Next i
        On Error GoTo 0
    End With
End Sub
```

To delete Shapes of a slidemaster, use this

```
Sub DeleteSlideMasterShapes()
    Dim i As Long
    Dim shp As Shape

    With ActivePresentation
        For i = .Designs.Count To 1 Step -1
            For Each shp In .Designs(i).SlideMaster.Shapes
                shp.Delete
            Next
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

If I have not understood your query then please feel free to ask

Answer (score 1):

Another approach, in case you want to delete all the shapes from all Slide Masters AND the master's layouts:

```
Sub DeleteSlideMasterShapes()
'   Including shapes on layouts

    Dim oDes As Design
    Dim oLay As CustomLayout

    With ActivePresentation

        ' For each slide master:
        For Each oDes In .Designs

            ' Delete the shapes on the master
            oDes.SlideMaster.Shapes.Range.Delete

            ' Then delete the shapes from each layout under
            ' the slide master:
            For Each oLay In oDes.SlideMaster.CustomLayouts
                oLay.Shapes.Range.Delete
            Next

        Next

    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Hey Steve, thank you for the approach. I would like to test it but I am very new to VBA, 2 days, and wouldn't know how to interface into Sub loopFiles()

Comment: You've already done it ... just replace your DeleteSlideMasterShapes sub with mine.

Comment: I get the following error with what I have together, Compile error: User-defined type not defined at Sub loopFiles()

Comment: On the "Dim fso As New FileSystemObject" line?  If so, use Tools | References to add a reference to "Microsoft Scripting Runtime"